How can I resolve Guice/MissingImplementation error when it seems like there is an implementation?
In my test:
package com.megafarad.play.kafka.module

import com.google.inject.name.Names
import com.megafarad.play.kafka.services.KafkaProducerService
import io.github.embeddedkafka.EmbeddedKafka
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.scalatest.Assertion
import org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerTest
import play.api.inject.{BindingKey, QualifierInstance}

import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

class TestModuleSpec extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerTest with EmbeddedKafka with Eventually {

  "TestModule" should {
    "Bind named instances of KafkaProducerService" in {
      withRunningKafka {
        //Arrange
        val producer1 = app.injector.instanceOf(BindingKey(classOf[KafkaProducerService[String, String]],
          Some(QualifierInstance(Names.named("producer1")))))
        val producer2 = app.injector.instanceOf(BindingKey(classOf[KafkaProducerService[String, String]],
          Some(QualifierInstance(Names.named("producer2")))))
        val producer3 = app.injector.instanceOf(BindingKey(classOf[KafkaProducerService[String, String]],
          Some(QualifierInstance(Names.named("producer3")))))

        //Act
        producer1.sendSync("topic1", "key", "value")
        producer2.sendSync("topic2", "key", "value")
        producer3.sendSync("topic3", "key", "value")

        //Assert
        assertMessageCount("topic1", 1)
        assertMessageCount("topic2", 1)
        assertMessageCount("topic3", 1)
      }
    }
  }

  def assertMessageCount(topic: String, count: Int): Assertion = {
    implicit val deserializer: StringDeserializer = new StringDeserializer
    EmbeddedKafka
      .withConsumer[String, String, org.scalatest.Assertion] {
        consumer =>
          consumer.subscribe(Set(topic).asJava)
          eventually {
            assert(consumer.poll(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(1000)).count() == count)
          }
      }
  }
}


I'm getting the following error on the assignment to producer1:
Guice configuration errors:

1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for KafkaProducerService annotated with @Named("producer1") was bound.

Did you mean?
    * KafkaProducerService<String, String> annotated with @Named("producer1") bound at TestModule.provideProducer1Service(TestModule.scala:74)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> TestModule

    * KafkaProducerService<String, String> annotated with @Named("producer2") bound at TestModule.provideProducer2Service(TestModule.scala:86)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> TestModule

    * KafkaProducerService<String, String> annotated with @Named("producer3") bound at TestModule.provideProducer3Service(TestModule.scala:98)
      \_ installed by: Modules$OverrideModule -> TestModule


It seems as if it should match the first binding Guice cites under "Did you mean?"
I did notice that the error message seemed to be missing the type parameters <String, String>, so on a whim I tried creating a TestKafkaProducerService:
package com.megafarad.play.kafka.services

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle

import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

class TestKafkaProducerService @Inject()(config: Configuration,
                                        producerConfig: Configuration,
                                        metrics: MeterRegistry,
                                        applicationLifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
  extends KafkaProducerService[String, String](config, producerConfig, metrics, applicationLifecycle)

...and replaced references to KafkaProducerService[String, String] with TestKafkaProducerService.
And... it worked! Well... it worked after I adjusted the timeout on the eventually block:
          eventually(timeout(30.seconds)) {
            assert(consumer.poll(java.time.Duration.ofMillis(1000)).count() == count)
          }

So... I guess the question I'm left with: is it possible to get a bound instance of a class that has type parameters in a test?

I'm not sure what instanceOf method offers to find a binding but the issue with your current usage is that classOf[KafkaProducerService[String, String]] is the same as classOf[KafkaProducerService[Any, Any]]: type parameters are not retained in classOf.
